# How to avoid usage of Task.Delay while scrolling to a particular point in Scroll View as I am adding children in runtime which are out of view?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, nullreferenceexception, android-scrollview

Here, I have used a scroll view and children are added upto visible height and the other children are added in runtime while scrolling down. Hence I need to scrollTo a particular point like Scrollview.ScrollTo(x,y) for this I need to calculate y by adding children height.Height is calculated by using delay to bring the view in screen first and I calculate. But need to calculate once the children displayed while scrolling without delay

```
ScrollViewer.ScrollTo(0, (int)totalheight);
await Task.Delay(500);
totalheight += this.CalculateHeight(ScrollView.GetChildrenAt(i));
```

Where children view height is return in the last method, but without delay the view become null.

Comment: You will need to include a bit more of your code. The ScrollViewer.Measure call is synchronous and doesn't need to be awaited.

Comment: It is best if you edit your question and add the code that surrounds the part that you posted.

Comment: If this is all you can come up with for your question i doubt we will be able to help you

Comment: Sounds like you should be using a UITableView (iOS) and a RecyclerView (Android). Not a ScrollView.

Comment: Could you give me more code about your issue? Or share a demo, that i can test it for you.